# SQL Server Aggregate / Grouping dates and summing them up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A card gets swipe multiple times in a single day, The data I have with me is Card number and Date in a table. I am trying create a User defined function to aggregate them and show number of swipes in a new column.

I'll be passing the card number as the input.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
5678907 2017-06-11  
5678907 2017-06-11  
5678907 2017-06-11  
5678907 2017-06-14  
5678907 2017-06-15
```

Output

```
5678907 2017-06-11  3  
5678907 2017-06-14  1  
5678907 2017-06-15  1
```

Comment: use `COUNT()` : google "mysql count group by"

Answer (score 1):

Simply use of `group by` clause with aggregation function `count()`

```
select Card, [date], count([date]) [Swipecount] from table
group by Card, [date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is -

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
[Card number],[Date],COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Card number],[Date]) cnt
FROM yourtableName
```

Also please use COUNT(*) if you are using group by. COUNT(Date) /*Count(Column) - ignores the NULL values*/ and if one of the date is NULL then you will 0 as output.

```
            SELECT [Card number],[Date],COUNT(*)  cnt
            FROM 
            (
                select 5678907 [Card number],'2017-06-11' [Date]  UNION ALL 
                select 5678907 ,'2017-06-11'   UNION ALL 
                select 5678907 ,'2017-06-11'   UNION ALL  
                select 5678907 ,'2017-06-14'   UNION ALL 
                select 5678907 ,NULL 
            )t
            GROUP BY [Card number],[Date]

            /*------------------------
            OUTPUT 
            ------------------------*/
            Card number Date       cnt
            ----------- ---------- -----------
            5678907     NULL       1
            5678907     2017-06-11 3
            5678907     2017-06-14 1

            (3 row(s) affected)
```